# How can you create a DLL in Visual Studio Code 2019 if you have a CSPROJ file and CS files?

Tags: c#, dll, csproj

How can you create a DLL in Visual Studio Code 2019 if you have a CSPROJ file and CS files?

We decompiled the DLL and then opened it in Visual Studio.  We can change what we need to, but then we're stuck.

Looking for step-by-step instructions in Visual Studio to create the DLL.  Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to "decompile" it if you have the source? Just make your changes to the code then recompile.

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies?  It's pretty rare that a dll is entirely self contained.  They generally require some nuget packages,do you have them too?

Comment: All I have is the compiled DLL to start with, and I do not know how to edit that.  When I decompiled it, I ended up with a lot of files, SIN files, CSPROJ files, CS files, Resource files, all in a folder structure.

Comment: Decompilers generate files that are compatible with Visual Studio, they do nothing to help you recreate the assembly in vscode.  Nor can you build .NETFramework assemblies in vscode.  The Community edition is a free download, simplest way to get ahead.